# Calculation of the avalanche effect coefficient.

Tags: hash-function

Given a strict avalanche criterion matrix/dependence matrix for a hash function,how do I calculate the avalanche coefficient for it.
I want to calculate a single parameter(value) which represents the amount of avalanche effect for the given hash function.

I have thought of computing mean all over the matrix but am not sure that's the correct thing to do.

The following paper talks about the avalanche coefficient but they haven't mentioned the way they calculate it:

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiStLSusvfLAhULnZQKHZHgBFwQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijsr.net%2Farchive%2Fv4i8%2FSUB157467.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGM96_VRx1IwzWg0VRsY0HRgNenIg&sig2=Yqk7QZaMQFDYbHTCkG821w

Comment: Your URL seems to be incorrect. That is, Google tells me the page does not exist.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, i will paste the complete URL:https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiStLSusvfLAhULnZQKHZHgBFwQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijsr.net%2Farchive%2Fv4i8%2FSUB157467.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGM96_VRx1IwzWg0VRsY0HRgNenIg&sig2=Yqk7QZaMQFDYbHTCkG821w